# Replace character in array and return result to the same array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs, react-redux

I pull some data from a REST service. The data is saved in `this.props.message`. In `this.props.message` I need to replace all "." with "," in `offerRate`, `prevRate` and `rate` and then save the data back to `this.props.message`. `this.props.message` will later be output in a table (react-bootstrap-table). The data can be edited in the table and before pushing it back to the REST service I need to replace the "," with ".".

`this.props.message` looks like this.

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
    addedDate:"2013-08-22"
    ccyCode:"CHF"
    country:"SCHWIZER FRANC"
    lastChangeDate:"2016-05-02"
    offerRate:7.02
    prevRate:8.501
    prevRateDate:"2016-04-01"
    rate:8.425
    rateDate:"2016-05-01"
    unit:1
    __proto__:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
```

`this.props.message` is then output in the table

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapTable 
        data={this.props.message}
        cellEdit={{
            mode: "click",
            blurToSave: true,
            afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell
        }}
      >
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="rate" dataSort={true}>Kurs</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
```

For the data edited in the table I have a callback function called `onAfterSaveCell`. This would maybe be a good place to replace the "," with "." before pushing the data back to the REST service.

```
onAfterSaveCell(row, cellName, cellValue) {
    this.props.updateData(row);
}
```

`row` looks like this

```
Object {ccyCode: "CHF", country: "SCHWIZER FRANC", unit: 1, rateDate: "2016-05-01", rate: 8.425…}
addedDate:"2013-08-22"
ccyCode:"CHF"
country:"SCHWIZER FRANC"
lastChangeDate:"2016-05-02"
offerRate:"7.99"
prevRate:8.501
prevRateDate:"2016-04-01"
rate:8.425
rateDate:"2016-05-01"
unit:1
__proto__:Object
```

I haven't managed to find a replace function in React. Is there any other approach I can take?

Comment: Why do you return a `console.log()` from your map, why not `return message.rate.replace(',','.')` instead, all though it looks like it's an array of numbers?

Comment: *"The array looks like this"* That's not an array, that's code for a `map` call. What does the *array* look like?

Comment: can we see your updateRow function ?

Comment: if you want to modify original array ... map() returns a new array and isn't the right tool for the job

Comment: @charlietfl What should I use instead?

Comment: a simple `for` loop or `forEach` would work fine and reassign the property value using replace on existing value

Comment: PLEASE update your question with relevant data instead of showing [Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object]....  in a comment

Answer (score 0):

There was a few things that got me off track. `this.props.message` is an `array` of `object`s. So first I needed to loop over the `array` to get the `object` and then loop over the `object` to reach the the character I wanted to change. The values in the `object` where not `string`s so I needed to convert them into `string`s to be able to use `replace` This is what I ended up doing.

```
replaceChar(from, to) {
    for (var i in this.props.message)
    {
      for (var p in this.props.message[i]) {
        if(this.props.message[i].hasOwnProperty(p)){
          if(p == 'rate' || p == 'prevRate' || p == 'offerRate') {
            this.props.message[i][p] = JSON.stringify(this.props.message[i][p]).replace(from,to);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I call above from the `render` method before it renders to the table.